# What do you have on your PXE server?

Tags: deployment, pxe-boot, utilities, netboot

Basically, what cool utilities does everyone have loaded up on a PXE server ready to use on any computer you netboot from? I've just set one up at home with the following:

- Clonezilla
- Memtest86
- Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Netbook
  remix 9.10
- Gparted
- Parted Magic

If I were to do this at work (and I plan to at some point) I'd probably add some sort of integrated deployment solution such as Cobbler as well. I'm just curious to see what other people have running.

Answer (score 2):

- [Darik's Boot and Nuke ("DBAN")](http://www.dban.org/about) is a self-contained boot disk that securely wipes the hard disks of most computers. DBAN will automatically and completely delete the contents of any hard disk that it can detect, which makes it an appropriate utility for bulk or emergency data destruction.
- [Breakin](http://www.advancedclustering.com/software/breakin.html) is Advanced Clustering's stress-test and hardware diagnostics tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to set mine up but the first thing I'll be putting on it is Bart PE, with all the plug-ins I like to have. I can no longer imagine life without it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of things, as evident by my iPXE menu (see https://gist.github.com/robinsmidsrod/2234639).

The one I use more often is SystemRescueCD, SpinRite and OpenELEC. I also have DBAN and Breakin, same as knweiss.